# Expected number of 5-sticker packs needed to complete a Panini soccer album

Tags: combinatorics, coupon-collector

To fill a football album of 200 stickers (images of players), how many envelopes do I need to buy if every envelope has 5 stickers and the album company says that all stickers has the same probability of appearing?

The answer is 233 but I can not reach it.

There is something I am missing (about the same probability of appearing: $0.5$?).

For me, I declared the variables $n=200$ and $k=5$.

Therefore, $$n!/k!*(n-k)! = 200!/5!*(195)!$$
My answer is $0.0254$ because something is missing, and I do not know what. Thanks!

Comment: Did you review [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101260/67822)?

Comment: I have edited the post to make it more legible.

Comment: @AntoniParellada I do not think he has such vast knowledge to grasp the concepts behind the link you posted. (I am assuming this due to the methods he tried).

Comment: Thanks but in the case of the link there is a probability of 90%. Here in my case there is not information about any probability of getting the stickers.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I need to know something: This is not a combinatory case? neither probability case? So what is the name of the math area that let me answer this question about the number of envelopes to fill the album?  Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like a variant of the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) in [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

Comment: Ross Millikan brought this up, but I'm not sure it was ever answered -- are the envelopes allowed to contain duplicates? Also, how do we know the answer is 233?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be modelled through a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) on $201$ states, labelled from $0$ to $200$, representing the number of stickers in the album. In we are in the state marked as $a$, we have fixed probabilities of transition into one of the states $a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4,a+5$, only depending on the value of $a$. For instance $a\to a$ happens with probability $\binom{a}{5}\cdot\binom{200}{5}^{-1}$, $a\mapsto a+1$ happens with probability $\binom{200-a}{1}\binom{a}{4}\cdot\binom{200}{5}^{-1}$ and so on. The wanted expected value can be computed from the transition matrix of such Markov chain (which is an upper triangular band matrix) with little numerical effort. Its closed form might be not so pleasant, but as already remarked by Ross Millikan, by the standard version of the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) it is reasonably close to $\frac{1}{5}\cdot 200\, H_{200}\approx 235$.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Very useful !

Answer (score 2):

The usual [coupon collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) problem, where you get the coupons one by one, would say the expected number to get a set is $200H_n \approx 200(\ln(200)+\gamma)\approx 1175$ coupons.  Naively you would expect to need $1175/5=225$ packs.  This will be correct if the stickers are randomly distributed in the packs, including the chance that there are duplicates in a pack.  I don't know how to calculate it, but suspect prohibiting duplicates will marginally reduce the expected number of packs.

Comment: Thanks Ross. That answer of 233 packs is a total mistery.